# How to understand Open Source projects/libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, struts2, ibatis

There are few open source projects/APIs/libraries that we use in our project (`Spring, Struts, iBatis` etc.) and I want to understand their design and how they work **internally**.

What is the best way to understand these projects? Note that I am already using these libraries in my project. And I know the input-output interaction/configurations for these libraries. What I don't understand is how these APIs/libraries work internally.

The problems I face is:

1. **Finding the entry class of the library.** Is there any way I can know the entry class for the library - something which is kicking the whole API?
2. **Tools/Plugins to use in Eclipse to get an overview of the design of the library.** Going through each and every class of the library, can be a very daunting task. Is there any tool you would like to recommend which can generate the class diagrams of the API in Eclipse.

Thanks in advance!!

---

**UPDATE**: I need some inputs on eclipse plugins which can help me in getting an overview/class diagram of the library

Comment: For anyone in the audience who writes open source software; documenting your code is what gets it into regular use.  Linus Torvalds is a hell of a coder... but also a hell of an evangelist and writer, which is why the world has Linux.

Comment: As was noted below, you must understand that not all frameworks / libraries actually have a main class. Sometimes this is due to the nature of the lib, and sometimes simply bad design (rotting architecture). The best bet for OS projects is usually the docs, and forums usually, and sometimes books. Trying to run tools on chaotic frameworks like (example) Hibernate will get you nowhere...

Comment: @Eran, I meant the entry class not the main class. Corrected my question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always use the same strategy for this: I never try to "understand" the code base as a whole,  and I usually try to follow the request flow. I read enough of the documentation to determine what is necessary to use the application, and I read *that* code (Keep all source code loaded in your IDE).

For example, in struts you'll be installing a servlet filter in web.xml. Start reading the filter and follow the path a single request takes through your stack.

Likewise for spring, there are two main entry points, the filter and "getBean", both of which are mentioned real early in the documentation. Read those two.

For both of these cases you'll find one or two classes that represent the "core" of the framework real quickly. Read those really well and let actual use cases & needs drive your further exploration.

Approaching "understanding" of an open source library (or any other code base for that matter) by trying to find all the pieces is usually not a very good way of approaching these things, it will usually just lead nowhere because a lot of these things contain too much code. When following the request flow I find making diagrams can also be quite distracting, it tends to draw attention/focus away from understanding (and since my understanding increases rapidly most of them are out-of-date even before they reach the printer).

Answer (score 4):

Nice question!!!, what I've done, specially in the case of Spring, apart from consulting the Documentation and their API's is to attach the sources of the project to my project on Eclipse, that way I'm able to navigate through the source code, not just the API. Its been quite helpful specially in the case of the Spring-Security project, there were some concepts that I just couldn't understand until I inspected the source code.

That's one of the advantages of using Open Source libraries.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks a ton for sharing your experience! But how to get a feel of the overall design, following classes by putting breakpoints can be difficult...

Comment: For and overall design the best advice I can give is to consult the project web site and check out the project reference... if any exists, I must admit that not all Open Source projects shine because of their documentation, especially when it comes to the design decisions they made.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like Structure101 (http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/structure101/index.php), and Lattix (http://www.lattix.com/) let you analyze code and produce architecture diagrams / dependency matrices.

This is not exactly class diagram - the main focus is on layering. So the entry point is usually the topmost layer.

But then again, as I specified above, you will notice that some libs are just a mess, and these tools will not be helpful enough.

See the S101 online demo: http://www.structure101.com/java/
This for example is the Sonar project architecture: http://www.structure101.com/java/tracker/sonar/1.11.1/arch.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for those three would be to consult the official documentation (make sure you are looking at the version you are using) or to get a book on the technology.

Answer (score 0):

Most APIs don't have a class with a main method; they're running in the webserver called by the server itself.  Unless they're running as their own server, they won't have a main method.

Comment: From "main" I meant the entry class which has most of the functionalities tied up.

Comment: @peakit: You're going to have to read the docs and the source; every project differs significantly.  You might try and start by finding whatever's loading the configuration files; that will load first or near first, and everything else will rely on it.